# Why is mining hashrate by monero-gui-v0.17.3.1 significantly slower than xmrig-6.16.2-focal-x64?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, cpu-mining, xmrig

I have been experimenting with solo mining Monero using two approaches on the same machine: `monero-gui-v0.17.3.1` and `xmrig-6.16.2-focal-x64`. The `monero-gui` reported a hash rate of ~6KH/s while `xmrig` reported ~10KH/s.

monero-gui:
[image: monero-gui]

xmrig:
[image: xmrig]

Questions:

1. Why is the hash rate of these two approaches different?
2. Is there any way to improve the hash rate of `monero-gui` or `monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.17.3.0`? Is there some options that I can apply to the `monerod`?
3. Where can I find the documentation of the mining algorithm used by `monero-gui` or `monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.17.3.0`?

To check the xmrig reported hashrate, I also experimented mining Monero in a pool for an hour. It fluctuated between 4KH/s to 17KH/s and achieved an hourly hashrate of 10.42KH/s (see below). Although I did not see such large fluctuations in hashrate on my local terminal as it always maintained around ~10KH/s, this result shows the hashrate reported by xmrig is reliable/consistent. When solo mining with `monero-gui`, I have never seen the hashrate reach 7KH/s on this same system, meaning the computation algorithm appears to be substantially slower than `xmrig`. Given that the official Monero wallet is encouraged to be used and encourages solo mining to improve the decentralization of Moenro, a reasonable expectation is the `monero-gui-wallet` should provide a fast mining algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Monero wallet is a *wallet* that happens to also ask the Monero daemon to mine. XMRig is a **dedicated** miner – it is built to do one thing and do that one thing as best as it can.
2. No, not really.
3. https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/tree/master/doc